# How to drag and scroll in a div with jQuery

Tags: jquery, scroll, draggable

I've been looking around for some time now, but I can't find a way to combine these elements:

I want a 100% width div, with 1 row of elements. I need to scroll through this div, just like: http://jqueryfordesigners.com/demo/scrollable-timelines.html

So with a hidden overflow and such.

But now I want some sort of smooth ease when I let go of the mouseclick, so it'll be like a sort sweep. So when I drag the screen from left to right, and let go of the mouse, it'll move on for 1 sec and linearly slowing down. Hm, am I making sense?

Does anyone know of any scripts or some tips to put me back on track?

Don

Comment: A really annoying thing about that demo is that if you click and move your mouse to scroll, and you release your mouse button when it is outside the content box, then it will act as if your mouse button is still depressed when your cursor reenters the content box, giving the feeling of out of control scrolling.

Answer (score 6):

*Utterscroll* is a drag and scroll library I've written:  (EDIT: demo temporarily broken, seems a CDN link no longer works,)

GitHub: https://github.com/debiki/utterscroll
GitHub hosted demo: http://rawgit.com/debiki/utterscroll/master/utterscroll-example.html

It differs from other libraries in that it 1) understands if you intend to select text, rather than scrolling (note that in [the example linked to by the question](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/demo/scrollable-timelines.html), it's not possible to select text), and 2) it needs no, or almost no, configuration.

Utterscroll stops when you release the mouse though (just like Dragscrollable, in the answer above, does.)

Comment: Why did someone downvote this? I'd appreciate if you left a comment and explained, or submitted an issue at GitHub instead.

Comment: @Kragalon Oh I hadn't noticed. The demo reachable via www.debiki.com is indeed broken. But this demo, hosted on GitHub, works: http://rawgit.com/debiki/utterscroll/master/utterscroll-example.html — I just added that link above.