# Make a div scrollable in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, tizen

I have a `div` in my HTML page that is populated with data from an XML file using JavaScript. Now I want to make it scrollable when the data gets lengthy. The `div` should move up and down on touch because I am making a page for a mobile app version.

I tried using `overflow:auto` and `scrollable` but it's not making the `div` scrollable. I am making the app for tizen.

I also used example from [this site](http://jsbin.com/azoji3/1/edit) but it has a button to scroll up and down, whereas I want to make the `div` touchable and make it move up and down on touch.

Comment: give your div `height` and `Max-height` then apply `overflow:auto` hope it will work

Comment: Try the answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3041498/how-to-drag-and-scroll-in-a-div-with-jquery There are two links to good examples there.