# How to make an HTML5 dragging element scroll the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop

Apparently they didn't natively add the ability to scroll the page while dragging an item. For my purposes, I need to be able to scroll a page. I know you can do draggable in jQuery, but I don't want to switch to this because I already have a lot of other things set up that rely on using the HTML5 implementation.

I figured you could get the `event.pageY` value while you are scrolling and if it is close to the bottom of the page, scroll down, and if it's close to the top, scroll up. I'm having trouble retrieving the values of `event.pageY` in my `drag` function.

Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dFPVr/21/). Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Using JQuery to scroll a `<div>`:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3041498/how-to-drag-and-scroll-in-a-div-with-jquery

Comment: I don't think you actually read what I said...